# Redux - get initial state from the backend - which is the proper way to do it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to get some variables from the backend (ie showTutorial) for the initial state in a reducer.

I was thinking about using just a call in axios from the reducer, but I am unsure if that is the best way of doing it.

This is how it is done right now:

```
import { UNSET_TUTORIAL, SET_FILTER_BLOCKS } from "../actions/types";


const initialState = {
  showTutorial: true, // <-- instead of initializying to true, do the axios call
  filterBlocks: "ALL"
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UNSET_TUTORIAL:
          return { ...state, showTutorial: false };

    case SET_FILTER_BLOCKS:
      return { ...state, filterBlocks: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I do not want to use redux-persist as I would like to understand first the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between how you do this and how you update state from a backend for any other component.

You should have an action triggered on a top level app component (or any component created at application launch) that loads data from the backend and dispatches the action with the results from  the backend. Your reducer then updates state based on this action.

The triggering of the action on your top level app component can be done using a lifecycle event when the component mounts, typically `getDerivedStateFromProps()`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to call the relevant action from App.js, and render 'loading' until the data is properly fetched. Obviously, in case of error you will not continue to render components but display an error message.

Reducers should never call actions, this is breaking the redux flow.